# Зависание операционки при установке доп.модуля RAM

Tags: память, ос, ram

Решил добавить оперативки в себе в ПК. Материнка - M2N68-AM SE2 (почитал в инете, максимальный поддерживаемый объем RAM - 4 Gb). При покупке стояла одна планка DDR2 2Гб. Решил купить пару одной серии, чтоб работали двухканально. При покупке делал стресс-тест всей системы в магазине в программе AIDA64. Все было хорошо. Но в процессе использования ПК заметил, что начались зависания операционки (не приложения какого-то, а именно всей системы). Минут 10-20 все работает нормально, а потом вся система зависает. Делая повторный стресс-тест, так и не дождался зависания. Если оставляю одну планку, причем не важно какую, то все работает нормально.
Короче начались танцы с бубном. Уже и так и эдак я их вертел, местами менял. Не могу понять в чем проблема. По описанию материнки.. 4 гб оперативы должна принять. И вроде принимает, запускается, в свойствах системы написано RAM - 4Gb, но работает нестабильно.
Заглянул в биос, но каких-либо настроек, которые могут решить проблему, не обнаружил.
Может кто-то сможет что-то посоветовать. Буду благодарен)

Comment: Чем делали стресс-тест?

Comment: написал же. AIDA64

Comment: Пардон. Не заметил. Стресс-тест в Аиде фиговый, одно название. Погоняйте Memtest86+ часов 12. Он ошибки в связке память/контроллер находит гарантированно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, насколько актуально, но может кому-то когда-то поможет.

Как оказалось, приобретенные планки были якобы Intel + AMD (а сам процессор Athlon двухядерный 245-ый вроде). Тестировал каждую планку по отдельности и обе в паре программкой Memtest86+ (спасибо *user194374*). В течение нескольких дней тестирования проблем с памятью выявлено не было.

В итоге, сходил в магазин, спросил, что мол за дела. На что в ответ: "Да, такое может быть, возьми эти, они чисто AMD-шные". Обменял, поставил, протестировал, и вот они уже почти три года красиво и беспроблемно работают.

Интересная такая ситуация получилась. Насколько я знаю, для памяти не особо важно, какой процессор стоит, да и в интернете на эту тему разная информация есть... хотя может на пике актуальности DDR2 это было критично. Может я и ошибаюсь. Буду благодарен за любые уточнения.

Comment: Для памяти неважно. К сожалению, важно для процессора. Правда, обычно с DDR2 ситуация обратная — многие двухгиговые модули, работающие с AMD, не работают с интелами.

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужна совместимая память, нужно чтобы было правильное кол-во банков и ранков, я так себе на CoreQuad поставил памяти в 2 раза больше чем он официально поддерживает. Ещё есть память для AMD, в ней разрядность (на 1 бит) для адресации колонок в памяти, что позволяет немного ускорить работу памяти но несовместимо с Intel, проблему можно попробовать решить установив меньшую частоту памяти и увеличив тайминги.